# Get rid of extensionname in realurl

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

I try to change my generated url from **http://www.example.com/page/extensionname/MyArticleNumber/** to **http://www.example.com/page/MyArticleNumber/** using Realurl 1.12.8 and TYPO3 6.2.27.
My realurl_conf.php:

```
'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'extensionname' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'extensionname_plugin[article]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_extensionname_domain_model_article',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(short_title, \'-\', juq)',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

What and and where do I have to edit to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your extension at one specific page you can use 'fixedPostVars'

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    # extension configuration
    'extensionname' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'extensionname_plugin[article]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_extensionname_domain_model_article',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(short_title, \'-\', juq)',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    # PID for extension configurations
    '99' => 'extensionname',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have make use of the `encodeSpURL_postProc` and `decodeSpURL_preProc` functions of realUrl.

The following code have I added to my `realurl_conf.php` file:

```
<?php
  $GLOBALS['realURLEncodeSpURLArray'] = array(
    'url/by/realurl/' => 'new/url/',
    'page/extensionname/' => 'page/'
  );

  function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref)
  {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace(array_keys($GLOBALS['realURLEncodeSpURLArray']), array_values($GLOBALS['realURLEncodeSpURLArray']), $params['URL']);
  }

  function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref)
  {
    $params['URL'] = str_replace(array_values($GLOBALS['realURLEncodeSpURLArray']), array_keys($GLOBALS['realURLEncodeSpURLArray']), $params['URL']);
  }

  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    'encodeSpURL_postProc'             => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
    'decodeSpURL_preProc'              => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc'),
    '_DEFAULT'                         => array(
       ...
  );
```

Please ensure that the `new/url/`should be unique so that there is no conflict.

By example: If you want to map txnews you got an url like `mynewspage/details/txnews/article` you should replace `mynewspage/details/txnews/` with `mynewspage/details/`. Do not replace `txnews/` with `/`!